# How to find out which application is requesting access to default keyring and make this request be postponed for several seconds?

Tags: startup, gnome-keyring

At start of DE the popup question from `/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon` for key-ring appears and i can't make right password with appropriate  keyboard layout. How can i postpone this request for a minute or so?
[image]

Comment: How long after does the right keyboard become available and if you wait can you do it then?

Comment: one minute enough. i want found out which process call that   gnome-keyring-daemon

Comment: The two I know are Chrome and access to the file services there I am sure others.